# How to use Metro's config to not look for extension when resolving a file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm trying to modify my metro.config.js file so that it will not ignore an npm package's `main` module.

This is the error message I receive at runtime:

```
error: Error: While trying to resolve module `@apollo/client` from file `<project-directory>/src/ApolloProvider.tsx`, the package `<project-directory>/node_modules/@apollo/client/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`<project-directory>/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * <project-directory>/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs(.native|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.|.native.|.|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * <project-directory>/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs/index(.native|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.|.native.|.|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (<project-directory>/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:311:17)
    at Object.resolve (<project-directory>/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (<project-directory>/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at <project-directory>/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (<project-directory>/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (<project-directory>/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at addDependency (<project-directory>/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
```

I can clearly see that `<project-directory>/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs` exists, but it appears that the resolver is always trying to append an extension (whereas the `main.cjs` file described above needs no extension).

The following is my `metro.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', ''],
  },
};
```

As you can see I've tried adding an empty string to the `sourceExts` property's Array, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Any idea how to get this Metro to resolve this `main.cjs` file correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently encountered this error and tried the same solution without success. The reason it doesn't work is because metro will still look for a file named `/path/to/file.js` and append `.` followed by the extension defined in the configuration array. Even if it's empty, it appends a `.` nonetheless.

I'm not sure if this will work for you, but in my case I didn't change anything in the bundler configuration. What fixed my issue was clearing the project's cache for *watchman* and *react-native*.

```sh
# Clear watchman's cache
yarn watchman watch-del-all

# Clear react-native's cache
yarn react-native start --reset-cache
```